# Arrays: Find array[x][1] for different x

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

First off let me tell you that English is not my native language. I have tried finding a solution to this problem on this site but I find it quite difficult to explain what I'm looking for in the searchbox. Please excuse me if a solution to this has been posted before.

So basicly I need to find `array[x][1]` for `x = input.readString()`

Example:

`array [0][0] = "book";`

`array [0][1] = "lord of the rings";`

`x = "book";`

I would now need a method that finds "lord of the rings" when the input is "book".

Edit: Please forgive me for not adding this in the first place. This is an assignment for school and I need to use arrays, not hashmaps, sorry for wasting your time

thanks in advance.

update:

gekozenCat is the input (book)
TERADENWOORDEN is the array with  [0][0] = book and [0][1] = lord of the rings
CATEGORIES = amount of categories

am I doing something wrong here?

```
  String woordVanCat = woordBepalen (gekozenCat);

public String woordBepalen(String teBepalenWoordVanCat) {
    for (int p = 0; p < CATEGORIES; p++)
        if (TERADENWOORDEN[p][0].equals(teBepalenWoordVanCat))
        return TERADENWOORDEN[p][1];
}
```

Comment: I tried something like Óscar López said but I couldn't quite get it to work. I'm trying his code now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    String[][] array;
    for (int i=0; i < array.length; i++)
        if (array[i][0].equals("book"))
            return array[i][1];
```

Comment: I have updated the original post with my attempt at your solution. However it gives me a 'cannot find symbol' error.

Answer (score 2):

A multidimensional array is not the best, in this situation. Use a Map, a HashMap:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("book", "lord of the rings");
...


String book = map.get("book");
```

Comment: It's actually an assignment for school where we need to use arrays. Thanks for the effort though. I appreciate it

Comment: Hehe well it's still a basic java class, I guess they want to teach us  how to understand this before moving on to more complex things.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you should be using either a `HashMap` or a `Multimap` ([found in Google's Guava library](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Multimap)) depending on whether you want unique or multiple values for each input you are looking for.

I believe that this is the right data structure for what you are trying to do, and moreover it is much more algorithmically efficient than searching an array.

```
Map<String, String> m = new HashMap<String, String>();    
m.put("book", "lord of the rings");

String out = m.get("book"); // returns "lord of the rings"
```

If you're getting the input in the array, I would stuff every row of the array into the map for more efficient lookups:

```
for(String[] row : array)
    m.put(row[0], row[1]); 

String out = m.get("book"); // returns "lord of the rings"
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I should've explained in the original post. This is actually an assignment for school where we need to use arrays.